# A committee of $6$ is chosen at random from $7$ men and $5$ women. $i)$ find the probability that $4$ men and $2$ women are chosen

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of $6$ is chosen at random from $7$ men and $5$ women.

$i)$ find the probability that $4$ men and $2$ women are chosen.

$ii)$ find the probability that fewer women than men are chosen.

**My working:**

$i)$ The part $a$ answer I have found to be: $Pr$($4$ men and $2$ women being chosen) = $\frac{{7 \choose 4}{5 \choose 2}}{12\choose 6}.$ Is my working Okay?

$ii)$ For second part I need help. I can't the write mathematical expression or equation of the statement: fewer women than men. How do approach it. any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

The probability fewer women than men are chosen is

- the probability that $4$ men and $2$ women are chosen (as you have correctly found), plus
- the probability that $5$ men and $1$ woman are chosen (find similarly), plus
- the probability that $6$ men and $0$ women are chosen (find similarly).

Answer (score 1):

A committee of $6$ members can be divided into two sets -

A) committee with less than $3$ women
B) committee with $3$ women or more

and notice that

$|A| = |B| = \displaystyle {7 \choose 6} {5 \choose 0} + {7 \choose 5} {5 \choose 1} + {7 \choose 4} {5 \choose 2}$

So the probability of having less than $3$ women in committee is simply $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In effect you are saying that if you divide the $12$ people into two committees of $6$ then exactly one of those committees has $3$ or more women and exactly one has $2$ or fewer